# Java: How do I build standalone distributions of Maven-based projects?

Tags: java, maven-2, build-process, build-automation

I often encounter distributions of Java applications or libraries which
use Maven as their build tool.

Some of them, sadly, don't provide standalone (or redistributable) jars.

Is it possible to build Maven-based applications in such a way, that
the **build result contains all dependencies** and can be redistributed to work out-of-the box?

I tried to build Jackrabbit's OCM module.
For some very "intelligent" reasons there is no downloadable standalone
version.
So I built Jackrabbit with Maven (the source package of Jackrabbit includes
OCM), and got the same jar as found in the **[apache repository](https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/public/org/apache/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-ocm/1.5.3/)**.
The jar **doesn't** contain necessary dependencies and is **useless** to me.

Comment: See my answer for Maven Shade VS Assembly. Shade is the clear winner.

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies

Answer (score 3):

As Dominic said, using the assembly plugin will do the trick. You would usually configure it inside your own project's POM to gather and package all required dependencies:

```
  ...
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ...
```

`jar-with-dependencies` is predefined by the assembly plugin and will include all dependencies in the final package (see the documentation  [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html)).

If you don't want to use Maven for your own project, you will need to modify the libraries' POMs and repackage them yourself (download the sources, add the above snippet to pom.xml and run `mvn package`). Beware of duplicate or incompatible transitive dependencies if you use multiple libraries. `exclusions` might help in that case (see documentation [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)).

Answer (score 3):

**Use the Maven Shade plugin**

...but be careful of the gotchas (similar to the one described further down my answer), which has got [a workaround explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586515/idea-to-avoid-that-spring-handlers-spring-schemas-get-overwritten-when-merging-m).

Also, be ultra careful with the Shade plugin config. I accidentally used double `<configuration>` tags once, and the transformers didn't apply at all, and the plugin also took the liberty of not warning me.

**Don't use the Maven Assembly plugin**

`assembly:single` will unpack your dependency JARs as-is, and this could not be what you want. E.g. stuff like `META-INF/spring.schemas` will be overridden with the last Spring dependency JAR that's evaluated, and as such your XSDs won't be found (apart from those in the last JAR, of course). Which is why systems like Alfresco made their AMP plugin which bundles dependencies inside `lib/` inside the AMP you're building. The latter raises dependency management issues, though.

Answer (score 2):

You may have some luck with the [appassembler plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/).  Failing that, take a look at the [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). That's more flexible, but lower level.  If you're using the assembly plugin, you may find the chapter on it in [maven: the definitive guide](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/assemblies.html) to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

As a couple of the posters said, the assembly plugin is a good way of creating a complete jar file, with all project dependencies. However, you don't actually have to modify the **pom.xml** file. Simply run:

```
mvn assembly:single -DdescriptorId=jar-with-dependencies
```

... in order to create a jar file. If you want to do anything more advanced, you should probably modify pom.xml, and create a custom assembly descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `pom.xml` file and use the `<Embed-Dependency>` directive. A similar example can be found [here](http://colab.interlegis.gov.br/file/lexml/ToolKit/trunk/toolkit/pom.xml?rev=4076) so you can adapt it to your scenario.

```
<Embed-Dependency>*;scope=!test;inline=true</Embed-Dependency>
```

I think this should do the trick.

---

Here is the example at the above URL that seems to give timeout.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.gov.lexml</groupId>
    <artifactId>toolkit</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>lexml</artifactId>
        <groupId>br.gov.lexml</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <build>
        <finalName>Lexml_Toolkit-2.0</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <!--_include>src/toolkit/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</_include-->

                        <Export-Package>*;-split-package:=merge-last</Export-Package>
                        <Bundle-Activator>br.gov.lexml.borda.Toolkit</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Bundle-Name>Toolkit</Bundle-Name>
                        <Private-Package />
                        <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=!test;inline=true</Embed-Dependency>
                        <Bundle-ClassPath>.,{maven-dependencies}</Bundle-ClassPath>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans-xmlpublic</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.gov.lexmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>lexmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Your link results in timeout. Please tell me where to put the directive. I can't find usable instructions on the web.

Comment: Just pasted the document comments inline in the answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, I'm totally new to maven, and, honestly, I don't even want to go deeper in it. So, I don't know: 1) Do I have to edit the main pom.xml, or that one of the desired module (which I want to build as a redist package), 2) The Bundle-Activator seems to be something related to your project, so how would I alter it to make it work? The main problem is: I'm doing everything remotely though SSH, so my flexibility of trying things around is very limited.

Comment: This solution appears to be specific to OSGi

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [Maven Shade Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) will satisfy your needs. I use it when I am building command line interface tools to create an Uber JAR including my classes and along with the classes from all my dependencies.

Its very easy to use and I think this [example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html) is self-explanatory.