# No suitable driver found when including the needed drivers with maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, jdbc, jar

I have a very small too that works with a PostgreSQL DB and it would be very convenient to use it as a single jar. So indeed I've tried using the maven-assembly-plugin like so:

```xml
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3</version>
<configuration>
    <archive>
        <manifest>
            <mainClass>pack.name.MainClass</mainClass>
        </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
</configuration>
```

And it works perfectly fine, I can see all the files I require added to the jar file, including the driver's files, but when I'm trying to run it I get a:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://<ip>:5432/dbname

I have this:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
```

In the dependencies and the URL is exactly as I wrote above (except the censored address). What am I missing?

Comment: you need to add that driver to your dependencies

Comment: The driver **is** in the dependencies... And the syntax is correct.

Comment: Do you have `Class.forName(...)` to load the driver?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you don't use `Class.forName(...)` to load the driver manually, then I think you faced an infamous problem with `maven-assembly-plugin` - it overwrites files with the same name when they come from different `jar`s.

In your case JDBC driver discovery mechanism relies on a file named `/META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`, and you have at least two `jar`s containing such a file in your dependencies (Oracle and Postgres drivers), therefore one of them is lost after running `maven-assembly-plugin`.

You can use `maven-shade-plugin` instead of `maven-assembly-plugin` to merge these files correcly, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586515/idea-to-avoid-that-spring-handlers-spring-schemas-get-overwritten-when-merging-m).

Alternatively, you can use `Class.forName(...)` to sidestep the failing autodiscovery mechanism.

Comment: Thanks, the shade plugin did great. That's an important "known issue" for maven-assembly-plugin we probably stay away from it...