# spring security login with CustomUserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hi i am trying to implement spring security for user login. My spring-security.xml file is

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd


http://www.springframework.org/schema/security


http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/home/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
        <form-login  login-page="/cart"  authentication-failure-url="/#/login?error=1" always-use-default-target="true"/>
        <logout />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService"/>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.dashboard.service.CustomUserDetailsService"/>

</beans:beans>
```

and here is my CustomUserDetailsService class

```
package com.dashboard.service;

import java.util.Collections;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

import com.dashboard.repositories.UserRepository;

@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Resource
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)     throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("here");
            try{
                SimpleGrantedAuthority simpleGrantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN");
                com.dashboard.Model.User userObj = userService.getUser(email);
                User user = new User(userObj.getUserName(), userObj.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, asList(simpleGrantedAuthority));
            return null;

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        //return null;
    }
}
```

and here is my UserService Class

```
package com.dashboard.service;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.dashboard.Model.User;
import com.dashboard.repositories.UserRepository;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Resource
    UserRepository userRepository;

    public User saveUser(User user){

        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public User getUser(String email){
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

}
```

here is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

 <filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml, 
            /WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

My problem is when i submit the form and debug the application, when i reach to line

```
 com.dashboard.Model.User userObj = userService.getUser(email);
```

my 'userService' object is null, can any one kindly tell my why the bean it is null. As far as my understanding i have declare a @service annotation in start of the UserService class, so shouldn't it create a new bean object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Autowired` annotated fields will only be processed if you declare a `<context:component-scan>` or `<context:annotation-config>`. You will need to add one of these.

---

Also note that annotating your class with `@Service` and `component-scan`ing it will create a bean for that class.

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
```

Putting a bean definition for that class

```
<beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.dashboard.service.CustomUserDetailsService"/>
```

will also generate a bean. In this case you will have 2 beans of type `CustomUserDetailsService` in your context. You might not want this.

Comment: thanks for your response, now i am getting 'The prefix "context" for element "context:component-scan" is not bound.' i search for a number of issues like this on stackoverflow but non worked for me.

Comment: @Shahzeb Notice how you have the namespace declaration `xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"` in your context file? You need to add the corresponding one for the `context` namespace. You will need to update `schemaLocation` as well.

Comment: i added and now i am getting this error "The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:component-scan'."

Comment: @Shahzeb As I said, you need to appropriate namespace declarations and `schemaLocation` value. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589470/the-matching-wildcard-is-strict-but-no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-co). You will also need the right library versions of Spring.

Comment: Thankyou so much. <context:component-scan> did the work