# The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:component-scan' error in dispatcher servlet

Tags: java, spring, maven, config

When I am trying to view the webpage on the browser I receive this error.

**stacktrace**:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 10 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/DefaultServlet-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 71; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:component-scan'.
```

DefaultServlet-servlet.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.projectShaun.controller" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Also I will include my `applicationContext` as it also have the same line of code in:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd">

  <tx:annotation-driven/>

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.projectShaun.controller" />

 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projectshaun" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
     <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.projectShaun.model.Account</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop 
         key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
  </bean>
</beans>
```

I also believe I have the correct dependency in my library and pom:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Answer from @Vladimir-tikhomirov says all.

Comment: Do you actually have only this dependency of springframework? I would assume that you might want to add _spring-context-support_ and _spring-beans_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589470/the-matching-wildcard-is-strict-but-no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-co) "*You have not specified the schema location of the context namespace, that is the reason for this specific error*".

However, it seems that you have it, so lets see what else can it be.

One option can be that you can specify the version of *spring-beans* because you are using 3.2 in your *applicationContext*, so might be beneficial to use the same one in *DefaultServlet-servlet.xml*.

Another thing which I feel worried is path *http://www.springframework.org/schema/p*, as I understand for this you don't need to specify the *schemaLocation*. It seems to be right, but I don't see that much of advantage here plus some of the XML namespaces are not used. So, I modified it and got this, try if it helps, hope it does.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.projectShaun.controller" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projectshaun" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.projectShaun.model.Account</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: OP have the schema location for context.

Comment: i just had to put each schema location on a different line.