# How to solve the error "The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'drools:grid-node'" in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am tying to build a project using maven but i am getting the above error,I have checked the pom that the jar is declared there but while i am trying to build i can see the error in the xml files.

This is my applicationContext.xml fil e

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xmlns:drools="http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
   http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring-1.5.0.xsd">


<context:annotation-config />
```

i am getting error in this line

```
<drools:grid-node id="node1" />
```

Can any one please help me how to resolve this error.I am opening the problems console in the eclipse and seeing this,[image]

Comment: Please show your whole pom.xml file.

Comment: @mateuszlo its too big how i will post  ?

Comment: Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/13589470/62162

Comment: @jwaddell i have also specified the schema location  in pom, see edit