# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'jaxrs:server'

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf, weblogic12c

I am getting the error when I delpoy app on weblogic server 12.1.3. The error shows on line where "jaxrs:server" line exists.

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 50; columnNumber: 61; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'jaxrs:server'.:
```

Here is my cxf-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xmlns:soap="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap" xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd             
        http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration  
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/core 
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd">

<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
<import resource="cxf-logging.xml" />

   <jaxrs:server id="restContainerBackend" address="/backend">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="pageframeworkServiceImpl" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="jsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
...
... //rest of the xml
</beans>
```

I am not sure what is wrong with this. Can someone point out please?

Thanks!

Comment: You might need to show us more, including `cxf.xml`, `cxf-servlet.xml` and `cxf-logging.xml`.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/13589470/18157 to see if any of the answers apply to your situation.

Comment: I already looked at some existing questions. But nothing helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs dependency was missing. Adding this dependency the issue got resolved.