# creating an uber jar with spring dependencies

Tags: spring, executable-jar

I'm trying to create an application über jar, but running into an issue due to a dependency on the spring framework.  In particular, the namespaces for the xml schemas are problematic.  You get the infamous NamespaceHandler problem:

```
Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/c]
```

For creating (simple) uber jars, [Creating a bundle jar with ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821803/creating-a-bundle-jar-with-ant), but this doesn't work if you have spring dependencies due to the fact that the spring jars have files such as spring.handlers, spring.schemas and spring.tooling in the META-INF directories of many of their jar files. The namespace resolution is dependent, I believe, on these files.

The über jar seems to somehow contain all necessary files, but I'm guessing the runtime is seeing only one.

For example, a jar -tf of my uber jar shows (in part)

```
META-INF/spring.handlers
META-INF/spring.schemas
META-INF/spring.tooling
META-INF/license.txt
META-INF/notice.txt
META-INF/spring.factories
META-INF/spring.handlers
META-INF/spring.schemas
META-INF/spring.tooling
META-INF/license.txt
META-INF/notice.txt
META-INF/license.txt
META-INF/notice.txt
META-INF/spring.handlers
META-INF/spring.schemas
META-INF/spring.tooling
META-INF/license.txt
META-INF/notice.txt
META-INF/license.txt
```

So: question.. is there a way to create an uber-jar that has the spring jars bundled inside?  Do I need to merge the META-INF files?  Anyone have experience doing file merger with ant builds?

Comment: Here's [another way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24083318/2208271) to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well.. this was a pain.

```
<target name="make-bundle" depends="jar">
  <!-- retrieve the dependencies -->
  <ivy:retrieve conf="deploy" pattern="${dist.dir}/dependencies/[artifact].[ext]"/>

  <delete dir="${dist.dir}/dependencies/uber" failonerror="false" />
  <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}/dependencies/uber"/> 
  <!-- iterate over the dependencies -->
  <for param="file">
    <path>
      <fileset dir="${dist.dir}/dependencies"> 
        <include name="**/*.jar"/> 
      </fileset> 
    </path>
    <sequential> 
      <propertyregex override="yes" 
        property="jarname"  input="@{file}" 
        regexp=".*/([^/]*)\.jar" replace="\1"/> 

      <!-- put the spring.* jars into special sub-directories -->
      <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}/dependencies/${jarname}"/> 
      <unzip dest="${dist.dir}/dependencies/${jarname}" src="@{file}">
        <patternset>
          <include name="**/META-INF/spring.*"/>
        </patternset>
      </unzip>
      <!-- put everything else in the 'uber' directory -->
      <unzip dest="${dist.dir}/dependencies/uber" src="@{file}">
        <patternset>
          <exclude name="**/META-INF/spring.*"/>
        </patternset>
        </unzip>
    </sequential>
  </for>

  <!-- build the concatenated spring.* files -->
  <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}/dependencies/META-INF"/> 
  <concat destfile="${dist.dir}/dependencies/META-INF/spring.handlers" fixlastline="true">
    <fileset dir="${dist.dir}/dependencies/" includes="*/*/spring.handlers"/>
  </concat>
  <concat destfile="${dist.dir}/dependencies/META-INF/spring.schemas" fixlastline="true">
    <fileset dir="${dist.dir}/dependencies/" includes="*/*/spring.schemas"/>
  </concat>
  <concat destfile="${dist.dir}/dependencies/META-INF/spring.tooling" fixlastline="true">
    <fileset dir="${dist.dir}/dependencies/" includes="*/*/spring.tooling"/>
  </concat>
  <concat destfile="${dist.dir}/dependencies/META-INF/spring.factories" fixlastline="true">
    <fileset dir="${dist.dir}/dependencies/" includes="*/*/spring.factories"/>
  </concat>

  <!-- build the uber jar! -->
  <delete file="${dist.dir}/myproject-with-dependencies.jar" failonerror="false"/>
  <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/myproject-with-dependencies.jar">
    <!-- all dependency files except spring.* -->
    <fileset dir="${dist.dir}/dependencies/uber"/> 
    <!-- the spring.* files -->
    <fileset dir="${dist.dir}/dependencies/" includes="META-INF/*"/>
    <!-- my project's classes & etc -->
    <zipgroupfileset dir="${dist.dir}" includes="myproject.jar" />
    <manifest>
      <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
    </manifest>  
  </jar>
</target>
```

Comment: You saved me at least a day of work with this. Thank you!

Comment: Where do I need to add this definitions to?

Comment: Your ant build.xml file.