# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd'

Tags: spring, maven

I am getting Exception and I am not able to figure out the reason why I am getting this error. Actually I’ve to produce an executable jar. When I run my class in eclipse it works fine. But, when I export this as executable jar using Maven plug-in it gives following error.  Following are the files for your reference.

**POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>Cubrid-Mongo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>3.2.10.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
        <spring-data-mongodb.version>1.5.2.RELEASE</spring-data-mongodb.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>CUBRID</id>
            <name>CUBRID-releases</name>
            <url>http://maven.cubrid.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-mongodb.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging begin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- log4jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.log4jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging end -->
        <!-- Database begin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cubrid</groupId>
            <artifactId>cubrid-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.4.3.1005</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database connection pool -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Database end -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>Cubrid-Mongo</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <!-- download source code in Eclipse, best practice -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Set a compiler level -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Maven Assembly Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>

                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.testloging.main.CubridMongoMigrationMain</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**application-context.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd">



    <import resource="test-context.xml" />
    <import resource="test2-context.xml" />
</beans>
```

**test-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <beans:bean>
----
------
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

**test2-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <beans:bean>
        --------------
-----------------------------
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

**Exception Which I get is below.**

```
D:\2016\Downloads\Spring\dbmigrationtool\target>java -jar Cubrid-Mongo-jar-with-dependencies.jar
18:07:21.905 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
18:07:21.912 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
18:07:21.913 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]

18:07:21.918 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@ccfcd
20: startup date [Thu Jan 07 18:07:21 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
18:07:21.960 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
18:07:21.960 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
18:07:21.960 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]

18:07:21.971 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [application-context.xml]
18:07:21.989 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader - Using JAXP provider [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl]

18:07:22.019 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver - Loading schema mappings from [META-INF/spring.schemas]
18:07:22.023 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver - Loaded schema mappings: {http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-
3.1.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/
scripting/config/spring-lang-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.2.
xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-2.5.xsd, http://www.spring
framework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spri
ng-lang-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd=org/springf
ramework/context/config/spring-context-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/s
pring-task-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.1.xsd, http://www.springf
ramework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spri
ng-context-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd=org/sprin
gframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/
spring-task-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.2.xsd, http://www.springfram
ework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-co
ntext-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.2.xsd=org/springfr
amework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.0.
xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/sc
hema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd=org/spri
ngframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config
/spring-task-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.0.xsd, http://
www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.2.xsd}
18:07:43.372 [main] WARN  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Ignored XML validation warning
**org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd',**
because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaWarning(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument1(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_79]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75) [Cubrid-Mongo-jar-with-dependencies
.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388) [Cubrid-Mongo-jar-wit
h-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334) [Cubrid-Mongo-jar-with-
dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) [Cubrid-Mongo-jar-with-
dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174) [Cubrid-M
ongo-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209) [Cubrid-M
ongo-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180) [Cubrid-M
ongo-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243) [Cubrid-M
ongo-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127) [Cubrid-Mongo
-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93) [Cubrid-Mongo-
jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130
) [Cubrid-Mongo-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) [Cubrid-Mongo-ja
r-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451) [Cubrid-Mongo-jar-with-dependen
cies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139) [Cubrid-Mongo-jar-with-d
ependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83) [Cubrid-Mongo-jar-with-de
pendencies.jar:na]
        at com.testloging.main.CubridMongoMigrationMain.test(CubridMongoMigrationMain.java:32) [Cubrid-Mongo-jar-with-dependencies.jar:n
a]
        at com.testloging.main.CubridMongoMigrationMain.main(CubridMongoMigrationMain.java:26) [Cubrid-Mongo-jar-with-dependencies.jar:n
a]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
        ... 35 common frames omitted
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 10 in XML document from class path resource [ap
plication-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 83; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the dec
laration of element 'beans'.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130
)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at com.testloging.main.CubridMongoMigrationMain.test(CubridMongoMigrationMain.java:32)
        at com.testloging.main.CubridMongoMigrationMain.main(CubridMongoMigrationMain.java:26)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 83; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
        ... 15 more
```

**CubridMongoMigrationMain.java**

```
public void test() {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "application-context.xml"); //Line No: 32

    }
```

Comment: Same here - you are providing a lot of details. Excellent input for a newbie. And btw: welcome to upvote level ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I think you are trying to assemble all classes and dependencies into one executable jar file. 
Based on the exception you are seeing, the Spring failed to validate the xsd.
If you open the META-INF/spring.schemas, you can see all the xsd configurations there.

You can try to use this plugin configuration file in your pom file:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>at.seresunit.lecturemanager_connector.App</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

You can also check out this link [Idea to avoid that spring.handlers/spring.schemas get overwritten when merging multiple spring dependencies in a single jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586515/idea-to-avoid-that-spring-handlers-spring-schemas-get-overwritten-when-merging-m)