# parsing xml cannot find schema file

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, spring, xsd

I have a requirement that my spring application must execute without access to the internet. I created my project in Eclipse and its file structure is as follows.

```
Project
  src/main/java
  src/main/resources
    META-INF
      bean.xml
      spring-beans-4.2.xsd
```

The beginning of the beans.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
spring-beans-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework/org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd">
```

I would think that the parser would find spring-beans-4.2.xsd because it is right beside beans.xml but it has other ideas. I have tried several different placements including trying to use the xsd file in the org.springframedwork list from Maven but I still get the following from the Eclipse XML editor.

```
cvc-let.1 Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
```

Actually if I can get this to work with your help I would make a directory and place all my xsd's in it. I am fully aware that this makes the bean.xml file dependent on these versions of the xsd but that's what has to be done to isolate the system. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`xsi:schemaLocation` is what establishes the association between a namespace URI and a schema to be used for the namespace. This attribute is a sequence of (namespace URI, schema URI) pairs. Your XML currently says that the schemas are on the Web at the specified URIs (such as `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd`, which works, but of course not when you are offline).

You can consider making these URIs relative, so that the XML processor resolves the URIs relative to the document URI. However, keep in mind that for this to work robustly, you now have to make sure that the schema file is always available at that location relative to the document URI. This is hard to do, hard for others to understand, and probably creates a lot of headaches later on.

A better solution might be to explicitly provide the schema file to the parser (instead of even using `xsi:schemaLocation`). This way, you would be in control of where the XML processor gets the schema from, and you would not create the dependency of the schema always being available relative to the document. You have to search the documentation of the specific XML processor to find out how to do that (because this is outside of the realm of the XML/XSD specs), but there very likely is a way to do it.

The existing question/answers "[what is the use of xsi:schemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875021/what-is-the-use-of-xsischemalocation)" might also be interesting to look at.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am going to try pursuing your 'better solution' and work with the XML parser. This means working with the GenericApplicationContext class which should be interesting. When I have working code I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed my original problem, have the parser only use local file and not use the internet. The key to the issue is a file called spring.schemas. If this file is built properly then Spring will not have to go to the internet to retrieve the XSD files. There are many references to problems with this file over the years but this link really says it all.
[Idea to avoid that spring.handlers/spring.schemas get overwritten when merging multiple spring dependencies in a single jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586515/idea-to-avoid-that-spring-handlers-spring-schemas-get-overwritten-when-merging-m)

In my POM I use shade to create an executable JAR file. Here is my latest POM.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
<artifactId>G</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>

    <!-- Generic properties -->
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <spring-framework.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

    <!-- Logging -->

    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>


    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <maven.build.timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</maven.build.timestamp>
    <jar.finalName>G</jar.finalName>
    <buildNumber>1.0</buildNumber>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependency for RMIO -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.healthmarketscience.rmiio</groupId>
        <artifactId>rmiio</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Test Artifacts -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.edvs.main.TestIt</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Date>${maven.build.timestamp}</Date>
                        <Version>${project.version}</Version>
                        <Build>${buildNumber}</Build>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

The two transformer entries at the end of the POM made shade to create the spring.schemas file properly. I include the spring.schemas file here.

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-4.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-4.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-4.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-4.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-4.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-4.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-4.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-4.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-4.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-4.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-4.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-4.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-4.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-4.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-4.2.xsd

http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-4.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-4.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-4.2.xsd

http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-4.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-4.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-4.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-4.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-4.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-4.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-4.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-4.2.xsd

http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
```

The entity resolver in the SaxParser uses this file to find the XSD files. Refer to site: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html section E.5.2. It states the following.

"The properties file called 'spring.schemas' contains a mapping of XML Schema locations (referred to along with the schema declaration in XML files that use the schema as part of the 'xsi:schemaLocation' attribute) to classpath resources. This file is needed to prevent Spring from absolutely having to use a default EntityResolver that requires Internet access to retrieve the schema file. If you specify the mapping in this properties file, Spring will search for the schema on the classpath (in this case 'myns.xsd' in the 'org.springframework.samples.xml' package):"

So if spring.schemas is correct then you are home free. One thing that struck me though when crashing through the code with the debugger, could I specify my own file specification for a XSD. I am not sure that this is possible because the code implied to me that if the specification of the XSD in the bean.xml did not match an entry in the spring.schemas then it would now load. I did not pursue further because once I got a good spring.schemas file then my parser worked without the internet. For completeness I include a simple test program and bean.xml.

```
public class TestIt {
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Processor.class.getName());

public static void main(String[] args) {

    logger.info("Started Version 8.0");
    TestIt testit = new TestIt();
    testit.run();
    logger.info("Ended");
    System.exit(1);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void run() {

    String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String fileSep = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    String fileNameXml = "bean.xml";
    String filePath = userDir + fileSep + fileNameXml;

    filePath = "META-INF" + fileSep + fileNameXml ;
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(filePath);

    DownloadService dc = (DownloadService) context.getBean("downloadBean");
    logger.info("Context loaded");
    ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)context).close();
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation=
  "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd

   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.edvs" />


<bean id="downloadBean" class="com.edvs.service.DownloadServiceImpl">
    <property name="serviceName" value="Download"></property>
</bean>
```