# Could not find definition for webservice at wildfly 9

Tags: web-services, maven, wildfly

I wrote a webservice and the building Maven is all ok, but the deployment on wildfly 9 receives error:

```
Could not find definition for service {http://ws.sieciowyandroid.rogal.com/soap/Map}MapService.
```

all log server: [here](https://ufile.io/6f09e)

wsdl is: [here](https://ufile.io/6b9ad1)
and schema: [here](https://ufile.io/6721b1)

and my code:

```
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@WebService(name = "MapWebServiceEJB", targetNamespace = "http://ws.sieciowyandroid.rogal.com/soap/Map",
        serviceName = "MapService", portName = "MapPort", wsdlLocation = "wsdl/api.wsdl")
public class MapWebService implements MapPort {
    @Override
    public GetThumbnailResp getThumbnail(@WebParam(partName = "in0", name = "GetThumbnailReq", targetNamespace = "http://ws.sieciowyandroid.rogal.com/soap/GetThumbnail") GetThumbnailReq in0) {
        GetThumbnailResp response = new GetThumbnailResp();
        try {
            response.setResult("czesc "+ in0.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.setResult("ERROR");
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

I did not notice a fault that could cause this exception.

I will be grateful for your help

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be related, but if you are using Maven to package the dependencies, then you may be stripping out the schema file mappings.  I had a similar problem with Spring Framework and the answer posted here solve my problem.  You can likely replace the spring references with the appropriate resources for your issue.

[Idea to avoid that spring.handlers/spring.schemas get overwritten when merging multiple spring dependencies in a single jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586515/idea-to-avoid-that-spring-handlers-spring-schemas-get-overwritten-when-merging-m)