# Problem configuring Jolokia server and agent

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, jolokia

I have a Spring Boot Java application that among other things uses Apache Camel to do a little route interception and data modification. We have a separate "camel routes" file (camelRoutes.xml) that defines the camel routes that will be used. There is also a bit of configuration in that file that, as best I understand, configures a Jolokia MBean server and Jolokia agent.

There is something about the Jolokia config XML that the system is not happy with. I've done some very quick Googling and it seems like it's specified properly (see section 9.3.2 in https://jolokia.org/reference/html/jmx.html). The problem manifest itself in various ways. When the file is open in the XML editor in eclipse, the corresponding XML is highlighted with an error (although it provides no information about what it thinks is wrong). More importantly, when I attempt to run the application, it fails with cascading exceptions, basically pointing to a problem in the config file.

Excerpts from camelRoutes.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jolokia="http://www.jolokia.org/jolokia-spring/schema/config"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
     http://www.jolokia.org/jolokia-spring/schema/config http://www.jolokia.org/jolokia-spring/schema/config/jolokia-config.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
...
<context:mbean-export server="jolokiaServer" />
<jolokia:mbean-server id="jolokiaServer" />

<jolokia:agent lookupConfig="false"
    systemPropertiesMode="never">
    <jolokia:config autoStart="true" host="0.0.0.0"
        port="${jolokia.port:8778}"
        agentDescription="${jolokia.agentName:jolokia}" />
</jolokia:agent>
```

Errors are displayed in eclipse for the line where the `jolokia:mbean-server` and `jolokia:agent` are defined.

Small section of the exception trace when application is executed:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 85 in XML document from file [C:\Users\JO24447\workspace\RST_Service_Base\rust-service-base-rest\target\classes\rst_camel\camelRoutes.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 85; columnNumber: 45; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'jolokia:mbean-server'.
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: I see similar problems and to me it looks like the Jolokia namespace does not get loaded properly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the cause was that I used the Maven `assembly` plugin which did not merge the `spring.schemas` files. I [switched to the `shader` plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5742390/2652567) and schema validation worked.