# Building complete application folder with maven

Tags: java, maven, build

mostly all java standalone-applications end up in a folder looking like this after they are deployed to production.

```
myapp  
|->lib (here lay all dependencies)  
|->config (here lay all the config-files) 
|->myapp.bat  
|->myapp.sh
```

I wonder if there is anything in maven with builds that structure for me and put it in a tar.gz.

[Java: How do I build standalone distributions of Maven-based projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015520/java-how-do-i-build-standalone-distributions-of-maven-based-projects) is no option. I dont want maven to unpack all the jars I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This kind of deployment directory structure is very popular and have adopted by many brilliant apps like apache maven and ant.

Yes, we can achieve this by using maven-assembly-plugin at maven package phase.

Sample pom.xml:

```
  <!-- Pack executable jar, dependencies and other resource into tar.gz -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals><goal>attached</goal></goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <descriptors>
        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/binary-deployment.xml</descriptor>
      </descriptors>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Sample binary-deployment.xml:

```
<!--
  release package directory structure:
    *.tar.gz
      conf
        *.xml
        *.properties
      lib
        application jar
        third party jar dependencies
      run.sh
      run.bat
-->
<assembly>
  <id>bin</id>
  <formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>src/main/java</directory>
      <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>*.xml</include>
        <include>*.properties</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>src/main/bin</directory>
      <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
      <filtered>true</filtered>
      <fileMode>755</fileMode>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>src/main/doc</directory>
      <outputDirectory>doc</outputDirectory>
      <filtered>true</filtered>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
      <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
      <unpack>false</unpack>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```