# Reading config resource from relative path for a Java app

Tags: java, spring, maven

```
--myjar.jar
--config
----appconfig.xml
```

I'm trying create maven based java application which can read configuration file from a relative path config\appconfig.xml

The idea here is that, the configuration can be modified without recompiling the application.

My implementation is something like this:

```
@Service
public class JooxXmlConfigurationServiceImpl implements XmlConfigurationService {
    @Value("${configuration.xml}")
    private String path; 
}
```

Where the value is fetched from a properties file that is uder `src/main/java/app-defaults.properties`
It works when the `String path` is defined as the complete address like: `C:/myprojects/myapp/config/appconfig.xml`
but I need to set the `path` to be something like `config/appconfig.xml`

Comment: What happens when the relative path is given?  I don't entirely understand where Maven comes into play.

Comment: When relative path is provided in, the error is cannot find specified file

Comment: Try `System.out.println(new File(path).getAbsolutePath());` to see how the system is resolving the file.  Keep in mind, that in Java, relative paths will be resolved relative to where the application was executed from (not necessarily where the application resides)

Comment: If your jar file is a classical command-line program, pass the config\appconfig.xml as a command-line argument, a better distribute format is to write run.bat and/or run.sh to execute the java program with extra command-line arguments. Check out answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151458/building-complete-application-folder-with-maven) to see how Maven generate this distribute format.