# How can I include external jar on my Netbeans project

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

When I run "clean and build" the `.jar` file that is being created only runs if the `lib` folder is at the same folder of the `.jar` file.

So if I move the jar file to the desktop and leave the `lib` folder in the `dist` folder, the jar file will give me an exception.

How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: erm , distribute the "lib" directory along with the jar?

Comment: Then, you force your users to download the dependency jars if they want to run your app. Pick your poison...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212913/netbeans-deploying-all-in-one-jar

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you copy your jars into the source code directory, they will be in your final jar. Nevetheless, I am not sure if this will work 100% of the time.

There is a great post at [java-forum](http://www.java-forums.org/netbeans/12582-netbeans-creating-jar-including-jar-libraries.html) that states the following:

> Except for a select few circumstances, what works best for me is to
>   simply merge the files manually. A .jar is basically a .zip with
>   organized contents, and you can open them in almost any .zip capable
>   archive program (I just use gnome's standard archiver, File Roller,
>   and it works great). Backup your jar file and open it in the archiver
>   of your choice, and do the same for each library jar in the library
>   directory. Drag and drop the working folders (IE, everything EXCEPT
>   the META-INF Directory) from each library into your jar's root path
>   (alongside your META-INF and your app's root package). Now drag the
>   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file from your jar to your Desktop or any other
>   folder. Open it, and erase the Class-Path and X-COMMENT lines. Don't
>   forget to leave a blank newline at the end of the file! Save the new
>   manifest file and drag it back to your jar's META-INF directory,
>   overwriting the old one. Test the jar.

Answer (score 23):

I solved this by creating just one jar file with all libraries inside, adding the following to my build.xml file in NetBeans:

```
<target name="-post-jar">
  <jar jarfile="dist/Combined-dist.jar">
    <zipfileset src="${dist.jar}" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="lib/commons-io-1.4.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="lib/ninja-utils-3.2.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <zipfileset src="lib/unicorn-1.0.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.example.mypackage.Main"/>
    </manifest>
  </jar>
</target>
```

This creates a jar file (Combined-dist.jar) which is the combination of the dist jar and the specified library jars (in this case, commons-io-1.4.jar,ninja-utils-3.2.jar and unicorn-1.0.jar). You have to be sure to specify your Main Class package for the new jar file or it won't run when you try to open it.

Comment: I added two jars to your example to help illustrate that you need to add one line for each jar you want to include. I know you can use a wildcard to add the entire lib directory, but I can't play with ant right now, so I'll post the simplest example (to avoid posting untested _code_).  Thanks a lot for this answer!

Comment: Just to note that it needs to be added just before the closing `</project>` tag in `build.xml`.

Comment: What is it says the jar (for example you Combined-dist.jar) doesn't exists even I create it. I'm changing the package in <attribute value> too

Answer (score 9):

*That's really easy to package every dependent library (*.jar) into one single myProject.jar.*

Just follow these steps and you will finally pack every dependent library into single jar. If you are using NetBeans then you can follow exactly or else you need to find your **build.xml** file in project files.

Follow these steps to edit **build.xml**

1) Click on `Files tab` on the left side of the project panel in NetBeans.

2) Double click on the `build.xml` file and add these lines in it just before `</project>` line

```
 <target name="package-for-store" depends="jar">
    <property name="store.jar.name" value="myProject"/>
    <property name="store.dir" value="store"/>
    <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>
    <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>
    <delete dir="${store.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${store.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
    <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
        <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
        excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
    </zip>
    <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>
</target>
```

3) Change `value` in second line of the code as per your project name which is

```
<property name="store.jar.name" value="myProject"/> //<---Just value not name
```

4) Save it and right click on **build.xml** and choose **Run Target** and then **Other Targets** and finally click on **Package-for-store**

5) And here you done. Now you can go and check just like `dist` folder there will be a `store` folder which will be containing your final complete jar including all of your dependent libraries. Now whenever you want to change / add more libraries or so, just follow step 4.

Picture for step 4

[image]

Comment: but why it's giving me an error on netbeans 11 ? lib folder doesn't exist...

Answer (score 5):

You could use Apache Ant since version 1.7 for build the JAR with the required libraries in only one file. You could have a configuration file as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="buildJar">
    <target name="buildJar">
        <!-- Name of jar -->
        <jar destfile="C:/MyJar.jar" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
            <manifest>
                <!-- Your class with the main method -->
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="myPackage.MyClass"/>
                <!-- Path in the jar -->
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
            </manifest>
            <!-- Dir of compiled class -->
            <fileset dir="C:/NetBeansProjects/MyProject/bin"/>
            <!-- Include required jars -->
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" 
                src="C:/NetBeansProjects/MyProject/lib/library1.jar"/>
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" 
                src="C:/NetBeansProjects/MyProject/lib/library2.jar"/>
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

In Netbeans, place the XML file in your project and run it with the context menu.

See more in [*Apache Ant User Manual*](http://ant.apache.org/manual/).

Answer (score 3):

**If you are going to distribute your app to another pc**

You just zip .jar along with lib folder.

**If want to run your app from any place in your pc**

Take in cosideration Maven way of doing this - create local repository eg. C:\libs where your libraries would exist and .jar could accesses them later from any place in your pc.

Or you could just use Maven. There is a discussion on distributing application with all dependencies (libraries): [Java: How do I build standalone distributions of Maven-based projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015520/java-how-do-i-build-standalone-distributions-of-maven-based-projects).

Answer (score 3):

Copy that jar file to:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\jre\lib\ext

and

> C:\Program Files\Java\jre\lib\ext

You should be able to use it in Netbeans and in your manual imports, just like standard imports.

Answer (score 2):

I have found maybe the easiest solution for this problem [here](http://%20oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/single-jar-141905.html). You just need to copy the next code snippet at the end of the `build.xml` file in your project folder.

```
<target name="-post-jar">

    <!-- Change the value to the name of the final jar without .jar -->
    <property name="store.jar.name" value="MyJarName"/>

    <!-- don't edit below this line -->
    <property name="store.dir" value="dist"/>
    <property name="temp.dir" value="temp"/>
    <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>

    <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>

    <delete dir="${temp.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${temp.dir}"/>

    <jar destfile="${temp.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>

    <delete dir="${store.dir}"/>

    <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
        <zipfileset src="${temp.dir}/temp_final.jar"
        excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
    </zip>

    <delete dir="${temp.dir}"/>

</target>
```

1. Go to the build.xml in the root of your project and add the code right before `</project>` tag at the end.
2. Now change the value of the first propertiy field as commented and save the changes.
3. From now on, each time you Clean & Build your project, the full jar with dependencies will be generated in the project dist folder

Comment: "I have developed"???  This was published 6 years earlier, with almost the same comments, by Robert Eckstein.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/single-jar-141905.html

Comment: @MikeHousky I edited the post to give credit to the original author. The edit was [rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15808434) because "This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive." I was perhaps misled by my time on outdoors.se, where [attribution is explicitly required](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/q/725/8887) for copied material. Here, it seems that attribution is not merely not required, but actively forbidden and regarded as "destructive" :(.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

I built in excel export functionality into my project. The 2 external .jars I used for this purpose was jxl.jar end sx.jar

Unpack these 2 jars into a folder(java classes) using 7-Zip without any META files. Unpack your project jar into the same folder including the META file.

Re-Pack the whole java classes folder using JARMaker to recreate your Project .jar in its original distribution folder ... and there you go ... full excel functionality.

Answer (score 1):

user1016588's solution works for me. There's one typo: this line should be
    zipfileset src="dist/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar" excludes="META-INF/*"

Answer (score 1):

Try this - in the Netbeans IDE:

1. Go to Tools --> Libraries
2. In the dialog box, on the bottom left click "New Library", give a name
3. On the right side, click on "Add JAR/Folder"
4. Click OK on the bottom right
5. Re-start the IDE and check.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these:-
1. Right click on project opened in netbeans editor
2. select properties
3. choose libraries
4. add jar
5. click ok

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this (when the libraries are not in "dist/lib"), tested with NetBeans and ant-contrib:

```html
 <target name="-post-jar">
  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
    <classpath>
   <!-- Path to ant-contrib -->
   <pathelement location="../../Libs/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
    </classpath>
  </taskdef>

  <!-- Change the value to the name of the final jar without .jar -->
  <property name="store.jar.name" value="${application.title}"/>

  <!-- don't edit below this line -->
  <property name="store.dir" value="dist"/>
  <property name="temp.dir" value="temp"/>
  <property name="temp.libs.dir" value="temp/libs"/>
  <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>

  <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>
  
  <fileset id="store.jars.absolute" dir="${store.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>  
  <pathconvert property="store.jars.relative" refid="store.jars.absolute" dirsep="/">
   <map from="${basedir}/" to=""/>
  </pathconvert>
  
  <for list="${store.jars.relative}" param="item">
   <sequential>
    <echo message="Adding @{item} into single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>
   </sequential>
  </for>

  <delete dir="${temp.dir}"/>
  <mkdir dir="${temp.dir}"/>
  
  <for list="${javac.classpath}" param="item" delimiter=":">
   <sequential>
    <echo message="Adding @{item} into single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>
    <copy file="@{item}" todir="${temp.libs.dir}" overwrite="true" />
   </sequential>
  </for>

  <jar destfile="${temp.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
   <zipgroupfileset dir="${store.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
   <zipgroupfileset dir="${temp.libs.dir}" includes="*.*"/>

   <manifest>
    <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
   </manifest>
  </jar>

  <delete dir="${store.dir}"/>

  <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
   <zipfileset src="${temp.dir}/temp_final.jar" excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
  </zip>

  <delete dir="${temp.dir}"/>

 </target>
```