# How to include jars in lib into project jar file in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, jar, package

I'm using some apache HttpClient jars, so I put them in my project's lib directory, when Netbeans compiles the project, it copies the lib and generated a project jar into dist directory, but when I run my project with webstart, I need to copy the project jar and lib into tomcat's ROOT dir, I wonder if Netbeans can generate a project jar that includes all the jars in the lib dir, so I don't have to copy the project jar and the lib dir into tomcat's ROOT dir. Can Netbeans do that ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, found the answer at the following site : http://arunasujith.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-build-fat-jar-using-netbeans.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 100):

*That's really easy to package every dependent library (*.jar) into one single myProject.jar.*

Just follow these steps and you will finally pack every dependent library into single jar. If you are using NetBeans then you can follow exactly or else you need to find your **build.xml** file in project files.

Follow these steps to edit **build.xml**

1) Click on `Files tab` on the left side of the project panel in NetBeans.

2) Double click on the `build.xml` file and add these lines in it just before `</project>` line

```
 <target name="package-for-store" depends="jar">
    <property name="store.jar.name" value="myProject"/>
    <property name="store.dir" value="store"/>
    <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>
    <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>
    <delete dir="${store.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${store.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
    <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
        <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
        excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
    </zip>
    <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>
</target>
```

3) Change `value` in second line of the code as per your project name which is

```
<property name="store.jar.name" value="myProject"/> //<---Just value not name
```

4) Save it and right click on **build.xml** and choose **Run Target** and then **Other Targets** and finally click on **Package-for-store**

5) And here you done. Now you can go and check just like `dist` folder there will be a `store` folder which will be containing your final complete jar including all of your dependent libraries. Now whenever you want to change / add more libraries or so, just follow step 4.

Picture for step 4

[image]

Comment: love you man, worked like a charm, I was struggling in Neatbeans for a SINGLE jar. I was using FAT jar in Eclipse and was missing an alternative in Netbeans. Thanks again.

Comment: @iltafkhalid You are welcome Khalid. Happy to see you happy.

Comment: run target is disabled after saving the xml

Comment: This definitely did the trick for me! I was having the same issue. Code still works fine 4+ Years later

Comment: i have few other depedencies file like abc.txt, is there anyway to put this txt file into main .jar file instead providing seperately with main file?

Answer (score 9):

[Robert Eckstein describes a solution](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/single-jar-141905.html) for this problem. You just need to paste the following code to `build.xml`. The libraries are all found automatically.

Here we go:

```
<target name="-post-jar">

    <!-- Change the value to the name of the final jar without .jar -->
    <property name="store.jar.name" value="MyJarName"/>

    <!-- don't edit below this line -->
    <property name="store.dir" value="dist"/>
    <property name="temp.dir" value="temp"/>
    <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>

    <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>

    <delete dir="${temp.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${temp.dir}"/>

    <jar destfile="${temp.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>

    <delete dir="${store.dir}"/>

    <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
        <zipfileset src="${temp.dir}/temp_final.jar"
        excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
    </zip>

    <delete dir="${temp.dir}"/>

</target>
```

1. Go to your build.xml, and add the code right before the closing project tag at the end.
2. Now change the value of the first propertiy field as commented
3. Click Clean & Build, and your jar will be in the dist folder

Reference link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30172829/2761273

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Barranka thanks for the feedback, this is a very good point! Will update it asap

Comment: This is not one line of code. Please update your answer

Comment: When he says one line of code, he means you copy and paste all of the above, then just change one line indicated to give your JAR the desired name.

Comment: The FAT jar file is not the one in the dist folder but rather the one in the store folder.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this is my solution. I too had the problem with my program compiling and running on Netbeans but it failing when I tried `java -jar MyJarFile.jar`. Now, I don't fully understand Maven and I think this why was having trouble getting Netbeans 8.0.2 to include my jar file in a library to put them into a jar file. I was thinking about how I used to use jar files with no Maven in Eclipse.

It's Maven that compiles all the dependencies and plugins, not Netbeans. (If you can get Netbeans to do this please tell us how.)

[Solved - for Linux] by opening a terminal.

Then

```
cd /MyRootDirectoryForMyProject
```

Next

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:compile
```

Next

```
mvn install
```

This will create jar file in the target directory.

```
MyJarFile-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Now

```
cd target
```

(You may need to run: chmod +x MyJarFile-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar)
And finally

```
java -jar MyJarFile-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Please see

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException

Answer (score 1):

1. check MainClass main file is updated as main file in Properties>run
2. Update Build.xml with following code before project tag closes

```
<!-- Change the value to the name of the final jar without .jar -->
<property name="store.jar.name" value="MyJarName"/>

<!-- don't edit below this line -->
<property name="store.dir" value="dist"/>
<property name="temp.dir" value="temp"/>
<property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>

<echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>

<delete dir="${temp.dir}"/>
<mkdir dir="${temp.dir}"/>

<jar destfile="${temp.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
    <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
    <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>

    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
    </manifest>
</jar>

<delete dir="${store.dir}"/>

<zip destfile="${store.jar}">
    <zipfileset src="${temp.dir}/temp_final.jar"
    excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
</zip>

<delete dir="${temp.dir}"/>
```

3. Properties>packaging> tick all
4. clean and build
5. Upload to server.

Comment: This is the best answer. Works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks Hasitha M Jayawardana :-)