# javafx swing application build jar with dependencies without maven

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, build, dependencies

I made a simple "JavaFX in Swing Application" in Netbeans IDE 8.0.2. After doing "Clean and build", I can easily launch my `.jar` if I have, in the same folder as the `jar`, another folder `lib` which contains all my dependencies. If not, it won't work.

The checkbox "Copy Dependent Libraries" is checked when I go in my project properties -> Build -> Packaging.

All the solution I can find is using Maven... I'm not.

I had the same problem with another project, but I ended up doing it all over again in Maven.. can I avoid that?

I also read about [Ant task](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm#BABFCGJJ) but I don't understand what it is. I don't know where I'm suppose to write the commands and if I need to install something or if I already have it... ?

If more information is needed, let me know in the comments, I have no idea why it won't work, so I don't know what kind of information I need to give.

Thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: I'm thinking this is probably a duplicate of: [Is it possible to create an “uber” jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832853/is-it-possible-to-create-an-uber-jar-containing-the-project-classes-and-the-pr).  The accepted answer to that question lists a maven based solution, but there are other answers that reference non-maven based solutions.

Comment: I'll go see what this is, thanks

Comment: @jewelsea none of these answers seems to work. Or I'm just not able to. Can't find anything clear on one-jar.

Comment: but found this, thanks anyway : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451052/how-to-include-jars-in-lib-into-project-jar-file-in-netbeans