# How to package java libraries that will automatically work when jar file is distributed to another computer?

Tags: java, netbeans

I've created an application which has a few external libraries, i am trying to distribute to another machine. I want the application to work from just the .jar file.

I know its something to do with the 'Resolve Project Problems', is there a way to prevent this when distributing to another machine

I have already tried adding a library to the distribution folder, it carries over but doesn't do anything with it

Run the application on a new machine without having to 'Resolve project problems' through net beans

Comment: A user who's name i didn't catch linked two very good solutions to my problem, I have reattached them since it seems like they have deleted their comment.

https://dzone.com/articles/java-chronicle-bytes-kicking-the-tires
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451052/how-to-include-jars-in-lib-into-project-jar-file-in-netbeans

The mistake i had was that i am using a dynamic file string
and the file path for the JAR was different than the filepath for the application i was using in the editor, i fixed this by just making a copy of the data folder and putting it inside the store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to Create a FAT jar

Two Useful links which helped me where

[How to include jars in lib into project jar file in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451052/how-to-include-jars-in-lib-into-project-jar-file-in-netbeans)
https://dzone.com/articles/java-chronicle-bytes-kicking-the-tires

This didn't entirely fix the issue, i was using a  dynamic file string with in my program

I copied the data folder from my application and pasted it in the store folder and rebuilt and also repackaged the fat jar. This made it work