# Forward slash '/' keeps reverted to back slash '\' .jnlp file in href statement

Tags: java, windows, tomcat8, jnlp, backslash

after web starting the .jnlp file from localhost and tomcat-apache running locally I always get the error that a .jar file is missing from java.  The message given reveals that the .jnlp file tries to locate the .jar file wrongly by "translating" the forward slash '/' I have defined in the .jnlp located in the tomcat webapps directory.

Specifically the .jar file I am referring to is in \lib directory (Windows) of the root directory where the application is deployed on the apache-tomcat server "\lib\mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar".  When running the Web App from the server and even that in the .jnlp I have altered those back slashes to slashes the error comes out showing a forward windows slash in the path.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" codebase="http://localhost:8080/sfp_levels/" href="JavaFX_SFP_db_levels_GUI.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>JavaFX_SFP_db_levels_GUI</title>
    <vendor>usr</vendor>
    <description>Test App</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="JavaFX_SFP_db_levels_GUI.jar" size="389828" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar" size="2464011" download="eager" />
  </resources>
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
  <applet-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback"  name="JavaFX_SFP_db_levels_GUI" >
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="8.0+"/>
  </applet-desc>
  <jfx:javafx-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="javafx_sfp_db_levels_gui.JavaFX_SFP_db_levels_GUI"  name="JavaFX_SFP_db_levels_GUI" />
  <update check="always"/>
</jnlp>
```

And the error comes back looking the .jar as "http://localhost:8080/sfp_levels/lib\mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar"

I have cleared all caches (Browser's and Java's) reinstalled Tomcat-Apache copied several times the correct .jnlp file to the webapps path in the server and signed the .jar files correctly from NetBeans (then Clean&Build)

I cannot understand where this windows forward slash comes into the href declaration after executing the Web App.

Version of Tomcat is 8.5.50
Version of Java (JDK&JRE) is 1.8.0_241
OS Windows 10

Comment: Are u hutting this issue https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8144165 ?

Comment: Yes! It is the exact error I get also

Comment: Ok. After looking into the .html file generated by NetBeans there is an entry under <script> tag that mentions jnlp_content: and has encoded the .jnlp file I suppose.  This is the actual file that is loaded whenever a .jnlp file is requested by the user lunching the web app. Editing the actual .jnlp file does not have any effect.  After enabling signing I guess that the .jnlp file is encoded and cannot be changed due to security reasons. I have to look a workaround on generating a single .jar file and signing it maybe not in NetBeans.  I wonder what the jnlp_content: will look like if possible

Answer (score 0):

Success! After generating a single .jar file following stack overflow's [single_jar_instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451052/how-to-include-jars-in-lib-into-project-jar-file-in-netbeans?noredirect=1) and [mkyong's](https://mkyong.com/java/java-web-start-jnlp-tutorial-unofficial-guide/) signing .jar file and generating a .jnlp file, I have managed to make my WebStart application to work.  Files where deployed on the same Tomcat Server I have tried all day yesterday to make it run with no success (Using NetBeans generated files in /dist directory).  This time it worked!

**Edit:**
looking more into it I found that in the original project as it comes out of NetBeans /dist directory if I eliminate all entries for scripting in the original html generated file and correct the '\' to '/' in the .jnlp file it runs correctly.  WebStart application appears and runs fine. Scripting from html file calls for /web-files/dtjava.js JavaScript auto generated file yet I cannot find where in that script it checks for the path of the jar it keeps getting wrong. I am using SeaMonkey as a browser launching the WebStart application.