# Error in preparing standalone Java application with external libraries

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I have made a Java serial Interface using RxTx libraries in Netbeans 7.2.1 which works fine.

[image]

Tested it with NULL modem and it works fine. Now I need to create an exe which I can distribute.

So,Now I am trying to make a jar file for my project. What I did-
[image]

and then clean and build to get jar at location

**"D:\Glaswegian\Java\Slides\RxTx\SerialCommInterface\SerialCommInterface\dist"**

with below structure
[image]

with lib having RxTx.jar

Now when I try to run from command prompt:
I get below error

[image]

Can anyone please let me know how to resolve this?

Have refered 
[Run jar file in command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774970/run-jar-file-in-command-prompt)
[How can I include external jar on my Netbeans project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834589/netbeans-how-can-i-include-external-jar-fileslibraries-in-the-jar-file-of-my)

But not able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system cannot find some native libraries (which probably are needed by RxTx).

Assuming that the native libraries (`*.dll`) are in the `lib` folder - try to run the app like this:

```
java -Djava.library.path=lib -jar SerialCommunicator.jar
```

Comment: Is the error the same? Have your tried using an absolute path (`-Djava.library.path=C:/SOME_PATH/lib`)? Also try copying the dll's to the directory where te jar file is located and see if it changes anything.