# jar file not performing all feature in another application with stacktrace

Tags: java

I am creating a standalone application in java. I create a jar file of that application by Netbeans IDE; `.jar` working fine in my system but not working all feature in another system. I am using jar library in my application. Exception is showing `Noclassdeffound`. This application scan qr code. This works fine in my system but even webcam in not open in another system. Please help me. Thanks.

stacktrace is as follows

```
C:\Users\Shubham\Downloads>java -jar JavaApplication1(2).jar
h3llo44444
hello world1111=null
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/githu
b/sarxos/webcam/WebcamPanel
        at javaapplication1.MainFrame.jButton2ActionPerformed(MainFrame.java:248
)
        at javaapplication1.MainFrame.access$100(MainFrame.java:33)
        at javaapplication1.MainFrame$2.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:104)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamPane
l
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 39 more
```

Comment: package name has space

Answer (score 6):

Noclassdeffound error is thrown when the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) or an instance of the ClassLoader class tries to load the definition of a class, but the definition could not be found.where a class has a dependency on some other class and that class is not accessible.

**In short at if you have used any external jar file than that jar file will be required at compile time as well at Run-time also in your case it seems that JVM is unable to find external jar file that contains WebcamPanel class at run time. so you need to pack that Jar file also with your application's Jar file.**

for how to add External Jar file in your project you can refer 
[How can I include external jar on my Netbeans project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834589/how-can-i-include-external-jar-on-my-netbeans-project)

Comment: I am not able to run jar to another system. Plz tell me some other solution thanks

Comment: how to create jar file which application import some other jar.