# How to make jar file with external jar libraries in netbeans 8.0.1

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I am using NetBeans 8.0.1 compress jar option in properties to make a jar file of my project.

I want the jar file to include some external jar files in the libraries. However, my exported jar file does not have external libraries, which I want to include. How to add external libraries to a jar file?

Comment: Possible duplicated with [How can I include external jar on my Netbeans project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834589/how-can-i-include-external-jar-on-my-netbeans-project)

Answer (score 0):

edit [Wrong]
I'm not really sure what you did, but usually libraries have JAR-files which you add using the Properties->Libraries->Add Jar/Folder button. 

When coding, you're able to use the library. When you build your project the JAR-libraries will be included in your new JAR. I've only used external libraries once, for reference.

Comment: The jar is created but the external libraries is not included. I have ucanaccess.jar external library. Is there any solution?

Comment: Ali Helmy linked a page where someone has a similiar question. I was wrong, the external libraries will be added in the Lib folder.