# Netbeans automatically cloning my jar based packages with their empty 'name equivalents'

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, sshj

I'm new at java programming so i just wanted to try something with ssh understand how it works and so i downloaded a java library which is  [mentioned in this Stack Overflow answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXYTK.png) 
. After a lot of failed attempts on importing this library into netbeans. I decided to simply put the files into my `src` folder. But Netbeans ide duplicating packages in the jar file with their 'name equivalent' empty packages and this prevents me to reach the classes in the packages because the IDE and the Code completion automatically sees the empty packs.I've search the network couldn't find anything about this problem.I 'm ready to share any log files if there are any of them .Here is my screenshot about this situation.
[Screenshot Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXYTK.png)

OS : Linux Mint Rosa

IDE : Netbeans 8.1 Linux version

Edit : I Already looked these topics

[How to use .jar files in NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975973/how-to-use-jar-files-in-netbeans) : At first i've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1975994/6184360) and in this solution netbeans not duplicating any empty packs but when i start to type somethin' like that `import sshj.foo.*;` Auto Complete can't find anything and also if i try to write the whole path to a specific class which is in an specific pack IDE gave me an error the pack that you're looking for is not exist.Secondly I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1976322/6184360)
and got the same issue at first try.I can see the packs,classes and other stuff but still can't reach them in a random class which is imported project.

[How can I include external jar on my Netbeans project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834589/how-can-i-include-external-jar-on-my-netbeans-project) : I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14879968/6184360) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26815310/6184360) ran perfectly without errors as they said but when i try to reach classes still got the same problem so nothing changed.

[How to add a JAR in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans) :
In this topic all of the replies explained types of libraries.That's **not** even related to my problem

[How to use classes from .jar files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460364/how-to-use-classes-from-jar-files) : I've tried to do explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2817176/6184360) reply also and I've transfered my jar file into a compiled .class extension file and this didn't solve my issue too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just solved that problem with downloading part of the libraries from [here.](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj/downloads)

All libraries need to contain three kind of jars ;

1 . Compiled files containing jar (with extension `.class`)

2 . Source files containing jar (with extension `.java`)

3 . Javadoc files containing jar (optional)

Open a project find `libraries` folder on ide right click and choose `Add JAR/Folder` specify the directory that contains the compiled files.After importing library hit right click over it and choose `edit` then specify the source files and javadoc files directories you are ready to roll.